# Aborted mysql connection no one can solve - need a true expert

Tags: mariadb, data

I have had several high level db admins look at my issue here and not a single one knows what the issue is.

I am constantly getting mysql error log spammed with

```
[Warning] Aborted connection 1650610 to db: (Got an error writing communication packets.
[Warning] Aborted connection 1650611 to db: (Got an error reading communication packets.
```

I have done everything every db admin has suggested including

- Raising max allowed packets
- Raising php timeouts
- Raising mysql timeouts
- Disabling all wordpress plugins
- Reinstalling wordpress / checksumming wordpress
- Disabling redis
- etc etc etc

None of the above are the issue. I've had several people look through web access logs, php error logs, mysql error logs, etc...There is no sign of why the connections are being aborted. But mysql (mariadb) is showing aborted_clients count increasing as these errors occur.

What reason could it be for these mysql connections to just abort for no reason? When I look at the access logs, the last query the connection makes is always a simple select query. However afterwards the connection gets aborted not due to timeout or packet issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. Does it matter / is anyone complaining? 2. Is it possible the client is legitimately aborting their connection or connecting from somewhere with an unstable network? 3. Perhaps this is an infrastructure problem, not a database problem. 4. You'll probably need to hire an expert regardless.

Comment: MySQL != Mariadb please correct your tags. The first thing I would suspect is an unstable network connection.

Comment: it is not due to unstable network. both mariadb and wordpress are running on the same localhost.

Answer (score 0):

- What version of MariaDB?
- Do any of these provide clues?

----- 2019-04-25 8.0.16 General Availability & 2019-04-25 5.7.26 General Availability -- -- -----

The [Aborted_connects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) status variable was not incremented for unsuccessful connection attempts, if connections were managed by the thread_pool plugin. (Bug #28490126)

----- 2013-12-03 5.7.3 Milestone 13 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- Performance -----

The LOCK_thread_count mutex protected several independent internal server structures and variables, and was a bottleneck, particularly affecting server performance in the circumstance when many clients were connecting and disconnecting at once. This mutex was decomposed into more specific mutexes and atomic operations to alleviate the bottleneck and improve performance.
As part of this work, the following status variables are no longer visible in the embedded server because for that server they were not updated and were not meaningful: [Aborted_connects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects), [Connection_errors_accept](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connection_errors_accept), [Connection_errors_internal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connection_errors_internal), [Connection_errors_max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connection_errors_max_connections), [Connection_errors_peer_addr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connection_errors_peer_addr), [Connection_errors_select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connection_errors_select), [Connection_errors_tcpwrap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connection_errors_tcpwrap).

----- 2013-09-21 5.7.2 Milestone 12 & 2013-09-20 5.5.34 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

A race condition in the thread pool plugin could cause status variables such as [Aborted_connects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) not to be incremented and permitting concurrent kills to happen for the same thread ID. (Bug #16959022)

----- 2013-09-21 5.7.2 Milestone 12 & 2013-07-31 5.5.33 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

With the thread pool plugin in use, normal connection termination caused the [Aborted_clients](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_clients) status variable to be incremented. (Bug #14081240)

----- 2013-09-20 5.6.14 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

A race condition in the thread pool plugin could cause status variables such as [Aborted_connects](/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects) not to be incremented and permitting concurrent kills to happen for the same thread ID. (Bug #16959022)

----- 2013-07-31 5.6.13 General Availability -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

With the thread pool plugin in use, normal connection termination caused the [Aborted_clients](/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_clients) status variable to be incremented. (Bug #14081240)

----- 2012-05-31 MariaDB 5.5.24 -- -- -----

fixes Bug #992983 MDEV-246 - Aborted_clients incremented during ordinary connection close The problem was increment of aborted_threads variable due to thd->killed which was set when threadpool connection was terminated . The fix is not to set thd->killed anymore, there is no real reason for doing it.. Added a test that checks that status variable aborted_clients does not grow for ordinary disconnects, and that successful KILL increments this variable.

----- 2012-05-31 MariaDB 5.5.24 -- -- -----

fixes Bug #992983 MDEV-246 - Aborted_clients incremented during ordinary connection close The problem was increment of aborted_threads variable due to thd->killed which was set when threadpool connection was terminated . The fix is not to set thd->killed anymore, there is no real reason for doing it.. Added a test that checks that status variable aborted_clients does not grow for ordinary disconnects, and that successful KILL increments this variable.

- Are you concerned about `Aborted_clients` or `Aborted_connections` or `Aborted_cnnects` or all?